# Using an external script in React / Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, reactjs

I'm trying to include an external script in my react component in Meteor. 
I've attempted just placing the script tag in my component like so :

```
TheLounge = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="main">
          {/* Uberflip Embedded Hub (Use this to generate the frame below) */}
          <script>var ufh_top_offset = 0, ufh_bottom_offset = 0;</script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://thelounge.tullyluxurytravel.com/hubsFront/embed_iframe?u=https%3A%2F%2Fthelounge.tullyluxurytravel.com%2Fh%2F%3Fembedded%3D1%26offsetTop%3D0%26offsetBottom%3D0%26hideHeader%3D1%26hideBanner%3D0%26hideFooter%3D1%26hidePriNav%3D0%26hideSecNav%3D0%26linkBreakOut%3D0"></script>
          {/* /End Uberflip Embedded Hub */}

        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  },
});
```

This makes it fine for the first time the page is loaded (via another page or a refresh). However, the script doesn't load up again when one navigates to another page and back.

So far I've attempted the following:

- Injecting the script in componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate like the following:

In componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = url;
// Tested the line below with body, head, and a div with specific id.
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script);
```

I've also tried using these packages:

- https://github.com/yariv/ReactScriptLoader
- https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-dochead
- $.getScript()

However, with all four of the approaches above I get the error:

```
Error: Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
```

I realize that's because the script I'm trying to load uses document.write();

I'm running out of things to try, I'd appreciate new ideas as to how to include this script into the React component.

Answer (score 1):

tags in body or templates aren't executed by Meteor, they are parsed and then handled by Meteor's templating system. try jQuery getScript function:

```
componentWillMount() {
  $.getScript('https://thelounge.tullyluxurytravel.com/hubsFront/embed_iframe?u=https%3A%2F%2Fthelounge.tullyluxurytravel.com%2Fh%2F%3Fembedded%3D1%26offsetTop%3D0%26offsetBottom%3D0%26hideHeader%3D1%26hideBanner%3D0%26hideFooter%3D1%26hidePriNav%3D0%26hideSecNav%3D0%26linkBreakOut%3D0');
}
```

Comment: Note that this will never cache the script

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this out, but I read this for blaze. Maybe it can helps

https://maxlibin.com/meteor-include-external-javascript-files/